# user agent style overrides inherited style in shadow root

Tags: javascript, html, css, shadow-dom

This works fine without using Shadow DOM:

```css
body {
  color: white;
  background: #532c79;
}
  
a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">HELLO</a>
```

The following doesn't work because inside the `ShadowRoot` the `a` rule from outside does not permeate in, and the body's `color` rule does not take effect despite being inherited because the user agent rule take precedence:

```js
const root = document.body.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })

root.innerHTML = '<a href="#">HELLO</a>'
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
  background: #532c79;
}
  
a {
  color: white;
}
```

This means that refactoring code to begin to use ShadowRoots is a bit of

Is putting the `a` rule into a separate sheet, then making sure each `ShadowRoot` imports it (with `@import` inside a `<style>`, or with a `<link rel="stylesheet">`, or with `root.adoptedStylesheets`) the only legitimate way to make this work?

I can also imagine monkey-patching `attachShadow` so that it automatically adds the style to each root, but seems hacky.

Here's a hijacked `attachShadow` example (but it doesn't work in Safari which has no Constructible Stylesheets yet):

```js
// before making any roots, before all app code, monkey patch

{
  const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet()
  sheet.replaceSync('a { color: white; }')

  const original = Element.prototype.attachShadow
  Element.prototype.attachShadow = function attachShadow(...args) {
    const root = original.call(this, ...args)

    root.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet]
    return root
  }

  const {get: originalGet, set: originalSet} = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ShadowRoot.prototype, 'adoptedStyleSheets')

  Object.defineProperty(ShadowRoot.prototype, 'adoptedStyleSheets', {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    get: originalGet,
    set: function(array) {
      if (!array.includes(sheet)) array.unshift(sheet)
      originalSet.call(this, array)
    },
  })
  // ^ or wrap it with another proxy to catch all cases
}

// continue like before

const root = document.body.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })

root.innerHTML = '<a href="#">HELLO</a>'
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
  background: #532c79;
}
```

And as you can see, it is getting complicated. I did not handle all the possible edge cases, and would probably want to make my own `Proxy` wrapper just like Chrome's.

There is no better way, is there?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are after (seems like your post is missing some sentences below the 2nd snippet)

- The `body` color trickles down into shadowDOM because it is an [*inheritable* property](https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/)
- inside shadowDOM `<a>` can be set to **inherit** the body color
- global style `<a>` is NOT inhertited, does NOT style shadowDOM

```js
customElements.define("my-element", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super().attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).innerHTML = 
       `<style>a { color:inherit }</style>
        Hello <a href="#">Web Component</a>`;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
  background: #532c79;
  font:21px Arial;
}

a { color:red }
```

```html
<my-element></my-element>
```